# How to verify a signature from the Phantom wallet?

Tags: javascript, phantom, signature, signing, java

I am able to sign a message on the client side using something like this:

```
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode("some message");
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
```

Now I want to verify the signature on the back end side using Kotlin (or Java).

**Problem**:

1. I cannot find the information about the algorithm that is used for signing messages [in the documentation](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/signing-a-message).
2. It seems like there are no Java/Kotlin libraries that work with Phantom and Solana (found a few which are not updated for a year).

**Question**: How can I verify a signature from the Phantom wallet using Java? Or generally how can I do that in any language? (I will port it to Java then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use the [tweetnacl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl) library to verify signatures.

```
const hasSucceededVerification = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
    encodedMessage, // the message
    signedMessage, // the signature
    publicKey.toBytes() // public key
); // returns boolean

console.log(`signature verified?: ${hasSucceededVerification}`);
```

[Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) is the signature system used on Solana.

You can find a complete example here: https://solanacookbook.com/references/offline-transactions.html#sign-transaction

Comment: Nothing to add to this answer, but in case it's helpful I have a codesandbox that does sign with Phantom + verify here: https://codesandbox.io/s/solana-sign-9exq14

Comment: @CallumM mind if i add that to the answer?

Comment: @ C_Ogoo of course not, go for it! :)

Comment: Just to add, since Solana uses ED25519, you may wanna try this for Java https://github.com/str4d/ed25519-java but I haven't done Java coding for so long.